# GraphDB - 1 vertex having multiple properties

Tags: cypher, gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Could you please help me understand if we can have multiple array properties in 1 vertex.. For example,

```
   "id": "CU10611973PH",
    "label": "Phone-Home",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "PhonePreference": [
        {
          "id": "c63cf5c9-329b-456e-b94e-0c500587780f",
          "value": "Primary"
        }
      ],
      "PhoneType": [
        {
          "id": "11f241d8-8e84-479b-b6a4-aeab7e039665",
          "value": "Home"
        }
      ],
      "PhoneNumber": [
        {
          "id": "5795e2ec-6d8c-424c-b42d-f01b587caeca",
          "value": "22222222222"
        }
      ],
      "pk": [
        {
          "id": "CU10611973PH|pk",
          "value": "pk"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "CU10611973PC",
    "label": "Phone-cell",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "PhonePreference": [
        {
          "id": "488c54b2-f256-4053-adc5-c07ec2e1a629",
          "value": "Primary"
        }
      ],
      "PhoneType": [
        {
          "id": "2f5263e7-f42b-487f-a185-338682a68fdd",
          "value": "Cell"
        }
      ],
      "PhoneNumber": [
        {
          "id": "a967516d-986c-4eac-929a-b86824677922",
          "value": "123456789"
        }
      ],
      "pk": [
        {
          "id": "CU10611973PC|pk",
          "value": "pk"
```

So here we are having 2 vertex, one for Phone-Home and one for Phone-Cell. Is there a way to make it come under 1 vertex with 2 set of properties .

Comment: I'm unclear as to how this is different to your other question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554552/querying-details-from-graphdb/68597858#68597858

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying details from GraphDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554552/querying-details-from-graphdb)